# Nesting where query to run faster in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, optimization

I'm trying to run this SQL code in a BI tool and that does not allow any set statement, temp tables or indexing.

This query runs for more than 30 mins as this a big table with millions of rows.Can anyone help me with nesting/subquery or any other possible way to make this run faster?

```sql
SELECT distinct d.id, d.value, v.site
     FROM dx d
     JOIN visit v
     ON d.id =v.id 
    where v.value like "I disorder, %"
    or v.value like "disorder,%"
      or v.value like "Other disorders"
      or v.value like "II disorder"
```

Comment: SQLite tends to be painfully slow, but 30 minute for 1 million rows is huge unless the number of columns is big or you put huge strings/blobs inside. With such timings, it might be faster to retrieve all the DB, compute it yourself and store it back... I am wondering if this could be due to the `distinct` keyword in the query. You could try to slip the request in simpler ones or simplify it so to see why this one is so slow.

Comment: Yes! I did have huge string blobs for this query but tried to minimize with one string even then the query took too long to show result.
One id has several observation so that is another reason. I need distinct ids only so cannot skip that, is there a way I can replace distinct here and use it in a different way to run faster?
Thanks